# "unpack" contents of an R environment object to current working environment

Tags: r, environment, r-environment

I want to achieve an effect similar to saving and loading `.RData` files like the following code, but without writing anything out to a file, and using environments instead.

```
a <- 1
c <- 3
save('a', 'c', file="file.RData")
a <- 'foo'
b <- 'bar'
load("file.RData")
```

So lets say I have some variables stored within an environment, some which share names of variables in the working environment

```
a <- 'foo'
b <- 'bar'
env <- new.env()
env$a <- 1
env$c <- 3
```

I want to unpack all the contents of `env` into the current environment, possibly overwriting some variables, such that the final values of each variable are

```
a = 1
b = 'bar'
c = 3
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a list from `env` and then use `list2env`

```
list2env(as.list(env), .GlobalEnv)
```

or equivalently as a pipeline

```
env |> as.list() |> list2env(.GlobalEnv)
```